# Accessing Recovery File - InDesign

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, file-recovery

I am wondering if there is a way to manually force InDesign to read it's recovery file. I tried to open a saved file last night, and it opened saying that the file couldnt be found. After digging through the library, I found what I believe the recovery file. When I open Indesign now, it says that it can't find any .indd files to recover. I am wondering if there is any resolve? The type of file I am trying to open starts with DBTemp... See image below. Please let me know if anything is possible to recover my work.

#### Screenshot of File

[image: Screenshot of File]

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not related to programming. You would probably be better off asking it in the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the DBTmpxxxxxx file and the DBSharingxxxxxx files in InDesign Recovery folder. If they are created using same version of InDesign installed, you might be able to open these.

Comment: Will try! Thank you.